# прошу помочь с картинкой

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Мне нужно что бы при наведении на фотку на нее накладывалась данная голубая рамка, рамка в формате png. Я сделал наброски но у меня не получается. Может я что то не правильно сделал, или есть какой то другой вариант!

```
<div class="bordered">
    <img src="images/photo-staff-1.png" class="by-picture" alt="">
</div>

.bordered{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

}

.bordered .by-picture{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100
}

.bordered:hover{
    background: url(../images/border.png);
    z-index: 200;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[image: фотография]
[image: Рамка на фотографию]

Comment: у вас должно быть в таком случае 3 изображения - 2 фона и фото. На фон наложите фото а при наведении фон меняете

Comment: рамка ваша должна не только в `png` быть, а ещё и фон прозрачный иметь. иначе не выйдет задуманное

Comment: спасибо большое, в голову идея другая пришла , все получилось

Answer (score 1):

Картинка `dbqUl.png` не оригинальная: я вырезал из нее фон.

```css
.bordered {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.bordered:hover:after {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/jnOOCiN.png');
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbqUl.png" class="by-picture" alt="">
</div>
```